# Home Page not Displayed For Project Imported From Git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, jsp

I cloned a Maven Git project and imported it into Eclipse Using `File>Import>Maven>Existing Maven Projects`. The project compiles and runs, but when I attempt to display a web page, the page is blank and when I use a web inspector I see Head and Body Html tags with no content.

The web pages are in `src>main>webapp>WEB-INF>jsp>home.html` or `login.jsp` which are among the files in use. In `web.xml` I have this entry:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Any ideas on what to look for would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some files are missing check your .gitignore file and it's restrictions.

Otherwise check **view resolver** prefix and suffix. If your suffix is .jsp and you have home.html it would not be found beacuse resolver tries to get home.jsp which doesn't exists.

If your prefix is other then WEB-INF/jsp then it's trying to find it in some other directory.

At last check what your controller GET method is returning. Now there are combinations of possible mistakes e.g. if it's returning home.html then it tries to find home.html.jsp which doesn't exists - **it needs to return only relative path from prefix and only the name of view without suffix**.

Comment: checked .gitignore and didn't have any files I needed listed. Created views.xml under WB-INF with the following content. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean> Tried to rename it to viewResolver.xml   Removed .jsp from GET method. No help

Comment: Renaming it would not help you. Configuration files go in resources not in WEB-INF.  To understand what WEB-INF is read Servlet specification (around page 70). Read this https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/

Comment: * 98. page http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1487076429_4d38acefa340c1a9a1e7f2da4f92da62